# App Script Не обновляется скрипт при обновлении ячейки

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Есть вот такой скрипт - он получает примечание в ячейку, но не перезаписывает изменения в примечании, вытянул один раз - и все. Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно кто-нибудь знает, как можно решить эту проблему и заставить скрипт перезаписывать изменения, или хотя бы обновляться самостоятельно раз в минуту например?

Сам скрипт:

```
function getNotes(sheetName, rangeName){
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName).getRange(rangeName).getNotes()
}
```

Comment: Простите, не совсем понял. Скрипт получает примечания. А должен что делать? Записывать примечание в ячейку или что?

Comment: Должен обновляться при изменении примечания, а сейчас просто получает примечания один раз, не обновляется если примечание изменилось.

Comment: Он работает по сути как функция ="ячейка", но вместо значения ячейки подставляет примечание, которое есть в ячейке. Пример работы =getnotes("June Plan";H5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Основной код

```js
/**
 *
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Range} range
 */
function updateHistNotesByRange_(range) {
  const values = range.getDisplayValues();
  const notes = range.getNotes().map((row) =>
    row.map((cell) => {
      const [last, ...rest] = cell.split('✅');
      return { last, rest };
    }),
  );
  const newNotes = values.map((row, i) =>
    row.map((cell, j) => {
      const res = [notes[i][j].last, ...notes[i][j].rest];
      if (cell !== notes[i][j].last) res.unshift(cell);
      return res.join('✅');
    }),
  );
  range.setNotes(newNotes);
}
```

Идея в том, что вы передаете в функцию диапазон и он обновляется как надо.

Пример использования при изменении данных пользователем

```js
/**
 *
 * @param {{range: GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Range}} e
 */
function onEditTrigger(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() !== 'Запись предыдущего значения в заметки при изменении') return;
  updateHistNotesByRange_(e.range);
}
```

`onEditTrigger` нужно зарегистрировать как триггер на изменение

Или пример сохранения с периодичностью

```
function timeBasedTrigger() {
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Запись предыдущего значения в заметки').getDataRange();
  updateHistNotesByRange_(range);
}
```

`timeBasedTrigger` нужно зарегистрировать как триггер времени

Эти подходы можно комбинировать в части размеров диапазонов, например, при изменении ячейки, входящей в конкретный диапазон нужно обновлять весь диапазон. Обычно это касается формул.

Пример работы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код в Таблице https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qDD9P6zMXImOqlEaEtIa2XzKZjGVOXcJ7S4nmPpIWvY/edit#gid=106780295&range=D2

Comment: Ого) Спасибо огромное! Вероятно точно поможет) Изучаю

Comment: @Ольга, вы можете отметить ответ как решение.

Comment: Отметила, но не сильно на самом деле помогло... Моя версия все равно остается, не могу только никак придумать как ее обновлять... мне нужно ссылаться на конкретную ячейку, а не на диапазон, потому что эти примечания по хорошему должны быть в отдельном столбце, но в отдельный столбец их никто не хочет выносить. Приходится дублировать таблицу на отдельный лист и добавлять вручную туда столбец с примечаниями. Функция из запроса в этом очень помогает, проблема в том что примечания меняют, обновлять эту функцию видимо только вручную....

Comment: Так разницы-то нет куда писать. Просто обновите назначение места хранения заметки. Ну, и как бы очень сложно знать ваше задание наверняка.